# What is the order of magnitude of bitwise operations involved in a SHA-256 hash?

Tags: hash, bit-manipulation

Specifically, how many bitwise operations (approximately, could be just order of magnitude) occur each time a Bitcoin ASIC miner performs a SHA-256 hash in typical mining computation, i.e. as it guesses the nonce and computes the hash of the 1 MB block to be added to the blockchain?

By bitwise operation, I mean the most simple state changes that occur on each bit.

Comment: You could read the SHA-256 spec and estimate this yourself.  Is there anything preventing you from doing that exercise?

Comment: Wikipedia has pseudocode for the algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode